# How to improve frequent BigQuery reads?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery for Java to do small reads on a table with about ~5GB of data. The queries I do follows the most standard SQL like `SELECT foo FROM my-table WHERE bar=$1` where the result will be at most 1 row. I need to do this at a high frequency and therefore performance is a big concern. How do I optimize for this?

I thought about pulling the entire data set periodically since it's only 5GB, but then again 5GB sounds like a lot to be constantly keeping in memory.

Running this query in BigQuery console shows something like `Query complete (0.6 sec elapsed, 4.2 GB processed)`. Fast for 4.2 GB but not fast enough. Again, I need to **very** frequently read from it but rarely (maybe once a day or week) write to it.

Maybe tell the server to cache the processed data somehow?

Comment: Processed data is cached by default. Clustering the table by `bar` column may increase read speed.

Comment: So if results are cached does clustering only help the first query?

Comment: Probably, yes. More about cache - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results
 You can try without cache - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-no-cache

Comment: Maybe you could benefit from using Bigtable - https://cloud.google.com/bigtable

Answer (score 0):

You don't have control over the Cache layer in BigQuery. That is something the service does automatically for you. Unfortunately typical cache lifetime is 24 hours, and the cached results are best-effort and may be invalidated sooner (Official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#limitations)).

Query completes in 0.6s seems to be goo for BQ. I'm afraide that If you are looking for something faster maybe BigQuery isn't the data warehouse for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is built for analytical processing and not to interact with individual rows. The best practice would be as you mentioned to hold a copy of it in a place that allows quicker and more efficient reading of individual rows (like a MySQL database).

However, you can still vastly optimize the amount of data scanned in your query by clustering the table on the field that you're filtering on.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables